# What game is this featured on the MSI Claw?

Tags: game-identification

What game is displayed on this image? It is a image of the announcement of the MSI Claw handheld PC.

[image]

This image comes from [this article](https://www.pcgamer.com/msi-has-launched-a-new-gaming-handheld-and-there-are-two-things-you-should-know-its-the-first-to-launch-with-an-intel-core-ultra-processor-and-for-some-reason-its-called-claw/). The article doesn't mention what video game is running on the MSI Claw.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That looks like [*Hades*](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1145360/Hades/), a roguelike that came out in 2020.

The UI matches up with this image from Steam, as well as the art style:

[image: hades image from steam]

Comment: If you want to find an image closer to what is shown on the original picture, you should search for images from the Elyseum levels